# "От читателя зависит исказить дурным чтением Гомера", или Что делать с цитатой?

Tags: выбор-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

«Искусство и истина», Ганс Зедльмайр:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну не можут мои ухи слышать такого русского языка, поможите, люди добрые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«... только от читателя зависит исказить дурным чтением Гомера и не дать состояться...»

*Только от читателя зависит — исказить ли дурным чтением Гомера и не дать ли состояться...*

Замена *чтения* на *прочтение* напрашивается, но не поднялась рука: два десятка заходов на прочтение фразы достаточно, чтобы почувствовать её сопротивление правке.

Comment: Спасибо за исправление в шапке - прозевала. Так, может, объявим войну переводу, - допустимо? Он же (перевод) несвеженький какой-то и маловысокорусский...

Comment: Ну так если поезд не ушёл...

Comment: Второе "ли" выглядит лишним: второй оборот по смыслу зависим от первого (про "исказить") и даже может быть заменен деепричастным.

Comment: Да, второе ЛИ выглядит лишним. Но я бы зависимость от первого здесь игнорировал: думаю, что и то, и другое — осознанные деяния.

Answer (score 1):

«... только от читателя зависит, **исказит ли он** дурным чтением Гомера и **не даст** состояться его откровению, его истинному присутствию в настоящем.

Я думаю, что некорректно сочетание ***зависит (что?) исказить.***